# Why is jQuery click-event triggered when page loaded?

Tags: jquery, events, click

I have the following code....
When the page is loaded myFunc() is called even if I dont click in my div. Why?
The function declared "inline" is not triggered...hmmmm........

```
<div id="map" style="background: green; height: 100px"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunc() {
        alert("allways triggered when page loads...");
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#map").click(myFunc());
    $("#map").click(function() { alert("not triggered") });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because of your code:

```
 $("#map").click(myFunc());
```

is wrong and has to be:

```
$("#map").click(myFunc);
```

Your code would call myFunc() first and than simulate a onclick event.

As seen in the documentation:

What you did is this: (as myFunc returns null)

> click( )
>
> Triggers the click event of each matched element.
>   Causes all of the functions that have been bound to that click event to be executed.
>   To trigger the click event on all of the paragraphs on the page:
>   $("p").click();

What you want is this:

> click( fn )
>   Binds a function to the click event of each matched element.
>   The click event fires when the pointing device button is clicked over an element. A click is defined as a mousedown and mouseup over the same screen location. The sequence of these events is:

Answer (score 3):

With the `myFunc()` in `$("#map").click(myFunc())` you’re calling the function references by `myFunc` and only its return value is passed to `$("#map").click`. If you want to pass the `myFunc` function itself, leave the parenthesis away and use just the function name:

```
$("#map").click(myFunc);
```

Comment: Good description of the error. I can add that functions that should be passed to functions, should be declared like: var MyFunc = function() {...}. However, most (all?) web browsers still accepts the standard declaration (function MyFunc()...).

Comment: @Björn: Your function declaration is not wrong. You’re just passing the wrong value to `$("#map").click` since `myFunc()` will call the function references by `myFunc` and then only its return value will be passed to `$("#map").click`.

Comment: Hu? My declaration? I'm not passing anything to JQuery, I often end up using Mootools ;) I think you're confusing me with the OP. I just gave a tip to declare the function in a proper way for passing it as a parameter to other functions...

Comment: @Björn: Ah, sorry, now I see. But there is a difference between a *function declaration* statement and a *function expression* statement. See http://yura.thinkweb2.com/named-function-expressions/

Answer (score 2):

Should be

```
$("#map").click(myFunc);
```

This way, you give the function as a parameter. `$("#map").click(myFunc());` triggered the function, and gives *its result* as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling your function in your click event handler. Do this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunc() {
        alert("allways triggered when page loads...");
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#map").click(myFunc);
    $("#map").click(function() { alert("not triggered") });

    });
</script>
```

You only pass the name of the function, *without parenthesis*, when passing it as an argument to an event handler (or any other function).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#map").click(myFunc);
```

NOT

```
$("#map").click(myFunc());
```

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
$("#map").click(myFunc);
```

and not

```
$("#map").click(myFunc());
```

passing `myFunc()` instead of `myFunc` actually invoke this function

Answer (score 0):

That is expected from your code because here:

```
$("#map").click(myFunc());
```

The parentheses () after the function  will cause it to be called.

Try this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myFunc = function() {
        alert("allways triggered when page loads...");
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#map").click(myFunc);
    $("#map").click(function() { alert("not triggered") });

    });
</script>
```