# jQuery click event fires immediately on page load, only in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, internet-explorer-8, click

Here is the offending code

```
$('.consejosTab').on("click", function(e){
    //window.location = 'http://encuentratrabajoonline.es/consejos/';
    console.log('Clicked' , e , this);
});
```

If you view the page http://encuentratrabajoonline.es/ in IE8 the page will immediately redirect to the subdomain. What appears to be happening is that instead of binding the click event to the element, this invokes a click function on the consejosTab. I've done some preliminary testing and i've commented out the relocation, and just put a console.log within the statement. I've also confirmed there are not other click functions that are running and clicking the element.

Aside from all the other abysmal standards on the page, (This is just the beginning of the cleanup i'm going to do on this site), I need to know why this is only happening in IE8?

Comment: Confirm that code is being called by putting in an alert() first - it might be that location is modified elsewhere. Also look for uses of `trigger()`

Comment: ok so you are saying that "what appears to be happening", to be sure that's what happening can you comment out the inside of the callback and add an alert statement, first step in debugging just to make sure that's where the problem is

Comment: I've confirmed that there is a click function on the element, what i'm not able to figure out is why the click function is initializing immediately on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of jQuery you are using (hopefully the latest) use this construct instead:

```
$('.nav').on("click", function(e){
  // your code here
});
```

Comment: `.click(fn)` in jQuery 1.7+ is nothing but a shorthand for `.on('click', fn)`.

Comment: This did not resolve the issue. Like I said standards aside, I need to figure out what is actually happening, as far as I can tell, the issue is the the click function being run, not bound.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for awhile as well, and found that I was invoking the call to myfunction unintentionally but as expected per the standard, [better described in this SOF question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558584/why-is-jquery-click-event-triggered-when-page-loaded).  By defining the function inline, it will automatically execute.

The following three syntax lines result in the same issue (immediate execution)

```
$('.consejosTab').on("click", function(e){ alert("I will execute immediately");});
$('.consejosTab').on("click",myFunc()); 
$('.consejosTab').click(myFunc());
```

A solution is to use either of the following options calling a named function - note the removal of the parenthesis.  Passing in 'myFunc()' is meant to return a value, passing in 'myFunc' is a reference to a function that should be executed.

```
$('.consejosTab').on("click", mmyFunc); */ JS */
$('.consejosTab').click(myFunc); */ JQuery Shorthand */
```